# How to change default 'Save As' path while using "attrib +r"?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

I have used following command to restrict edits to a file:

`attrib +r C:\temp\attributes.txt`

Whenever I try to edit and save them, I am prompted with 'Save As' dialog which has 'C:\temp' as default location. Is there any way for 'Save As' dialog box to always go to default folder of my choice which is 'D:\project' ?

Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). you can create a script like this:

```
loop{
; wait until the Save As dialog appears
WinWaitActive,Save As
; jump to the target dir
send D:\project{enter}
; wait until the Save As dialog gone
WinWaitNotActive,Save As
}
```

so when the save as diagol pops up, autohotkey will automatically switch dir for you.

Comment: Thanks. I am beginner with DOS and never heard of autohotkey. How do you suggest I should run above script?

Comment: google autohotkey. autohotkey is an open source software for windows automation.

Comment: The only problem with this ahk is that whatever file I am closing is leading me to default set for only one program. I want 'D:\project' to be used for only one program.